# Text floating over a figure or table

Tags: tables, floats, xetex, text

I have very big problems with tables and figures in my latex article. Why text floating over a table, figure?
Thats my preambla, packages:

```
\documentclass[proof]{WileyASNA-v1}
%\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{\arabic{mpfootnote}}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=cyan,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=cyan,
}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\articletype{Article Type}%
\received{XX X XXXX}
\revised{XX X XXXX}
\accepted{XX X XXXX}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage{caption}
\raggedbottom
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro{\UrlBreaks}{\UrlOrds}
```

And thats tables:

```
\newpage
\begin{table}[!htbp]%
\caption{XMM-Newton expositions for Gaia18awg\label{tab4}}
\centering
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep\fill}lccrc@{}}
\toprule
Instrument & Mode & Filter & Duration \\
\midrule
XRT& PC (Photon Counting) & - & 1200s\\
BAT& Burst/Survey & - & 1200s\\
UVOT& Image & W2 & 1200s \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}\vspace{-3em}
\begin{table}[!htbp]%
\caption{XMM-Newton expositions for Gaia18awg\label{tab5}}
\centering
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep\fill}lccrc@{}}
\toprule
Exp.ID & Instrument & Mode & Filter & Duration \\
\midrule
S001& EMOS1 & Small Window & MEDIUM   & 16626s\\
S002& EMOS2 & Large Window  &MEDIUM & 16604s\\
S003& EPN & Small Window   & MEDIUM & 16139s \\
S006& OM & Image & V   &4000s\\
S007& OM & Image   &U & 3999s\\
S008& OM & Image   & UVW1 & 4001s\\
S009& OM & Image & UVW1  & 3400s\\
S004& RGS1 & Spectroscopy HER+SES &N/A& 16911s\\
S005& RGS2 & Spectroscopy HER+SES & N/A & 16909s\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: If you want your table to occupy both column, use `table*` instead of `table`.

Comment: Thank you! Thats really helped.